# How should a new employee handle discovering data falsification by their boss?

Tags: united-states, human-resources, ethics

I have been navigating the workplace in hopes of finding a similar situation with a solution, but unfortunately I have had no such luck (perhaps by fault of my own). A friend of mine (lets call them V) recently confronted me about an ethical dilemma they are having and have reached out for my advice, to which I was unsure on how to proceed as well.

V has started a new position at their company, and has gone through several trainings on how to properly conduct their responsibilities and routines. These routines involve recording data that a program outputs. This process can be very tedious and sometimes require several program re-runs to get acceptable values. V has made sure to always perform the tests as directed, as tedious as it may be. Furthermore , V's boss has made it clear that falsifying any data would result in disciplinary action (most likely termination based on other departments incidents). Occasionally, with personnel outage, a higher up member will cover for a member of the team.

In comes the ethical dilemma. By accident V discovered several occasions of their boss doing exactly this, falsifying records which do not align with the recorded program output. (They frequently go through the logs as part of the process to record the data. They had noticed that the boss was able to complete the task much quicker with many fewer attempts and was looking to see if they (V) were doing something wrong, when they discovered the conflicting reports.) V is concerned about retaliation and has heard the old anecdote of *HR protects the interests of the company and not the employee*. V's boss is also very well liked and well respected by the higherups. V wants to do the right thing, but fears that even if the issue is resolved they will always have a target on their back. Due to the nature of the test, it would be apparent - even if anonymously submitted that it was V who reported it. The program that these values are used for is not life threatening and would not cause harm to anyone involved.

EDIT: To clarify,  V's boss recorded a value that was within the acceptable range that was never presented by the program and has no logical way of abstracting it (i.e. rounding)

What is the best way to report this kind of finding? What are the likely impacts to the career/employmeent of V in this case?

Comment: "this process can be very tedious and sometimes require several program re-runs to get acceptable values" so the boss hasn't rerun to get acceptable values? It sounds as though this program is inherently ill-functioning, and if it's really so life and death to report bad data, then it would be V's responsibility to report it. If there's retaliation, then it was never going to be a job that V wanted for very long anyway.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf Correct they did not rerun to get acceptable values

Comment: @conflicted-for-a-friend following on what kaizerwolf and you are talking, if boss "did not rerun to get acceptable values", then *technically* boss was not falsifying data, just inputting data that could have been better... mind clarifying the difference between falsifying and not rerunning the program several times?

Comment: @DarkCygnus, to clarify  they put in numbers within acceptable range which the program never output

Comment: What is "your friend"'s goal here? To have the program improved, to have the process improved, to have their boss reprimanded or fired, or something else?

Comment: Is this infraction on the boss' part a criminal act? Could it result in material, financial, or physical harm to persons or property? If not, my suggestion would be for V to worry about his/her own behavior and not worry about the behavior of others. People make their own choices. It isn't V's place to be the corporate morality/ethics monitor.

Comment: @conflicted-for-a-friend: What are the potential consequences of the data being wrong? The "ethical" aspect of this is very much a function of the impact of the infraction. People getting hurt or dying is completely different from "some numbers in an archive are wrong".

Comment: Your question is very misleading. If, as you say, the boss simply didn't run the program again, then there seems to be no ethical dilemma here. At worst, the boss made a mistake. But there was no falsification, no breach of ethics, no issue at all. So why are you saying the boss _falsified_ (meaning to invent fake data that prove the point the boss wants to make) data?

Comment: @terdon , The boss did not rerun the test and instead recorded an acceptable value that the program never indicated

Comment: I'm intrigued as to what "re-run" entails exactly, because the way it reads to me is that they're just retrying until they can cherry-pick the result they want. That would make the data inaccurate (it *could* be true but certainly not precise) by design and easily construed as false anyways. Hopefully it's only a case of details left out of the question, but speaking of ethical dilemma I feel it's useful to point out just in case.

Comment: As an aside, manually recording the output of a program feels like something that should be easy to automate.

Comment: I missed the part where V has anything to do with this.

Comment: Why does V believe that he/she has an ethical responsibility to report this?  That is not explained in your post, as far as I can tell.

Comment: @AmiralPatate, The test is used on a small set of data. Assuming that the small subset of data is deemed acceptable V is allowed to proceed with the full suite of tests. In the event it is not within an acceptable range, more processes need to occur before re-testing . Once a re-test succeeds (usually after several iterations of the aforementioned) the results will be considered valid. The shortcut is V's boss is running the initial test - seeing an unacceptable value - and recording an acceptable value as if that was the output .Thus giving the go-ahead to proceed with the full suite of tests

Comment: @conflicted-for-a-friend: That doesn't quite make sense...is there an additional cost to the company if the full-suite is run?

Comment: @conflicted-for-a-friend so if the full suite of tests works, then presumably the shortcut the boss took didn't cause any problems, correct?  Any problem in the full data set would still show up.  And in fact if there was a problem, it would reflect directly back on the boss, not V.  So I'm not seeing the problem here.

Comment: Is there no possibility of it being simple clerical error by the boss? Wouldn't the opening gambit be to simply present the error to the boss responsible?

Comment: @DaveG, the tests would work but the resulting data would not be valid.

Comment: What the heck are you doing that you can get different values? Some kind of modeling based on sample values? I'm very concerned that you are asked to do it several times in order to get the needed results, which are probably needed for regulatory purposes. All of this seems shady.

Comment: OP, you can drop this charade.  We all know there is no "friend" here.

Comment: Is "boss" the company owner or just your manager? If it's just your manager, he might be acting strictly against company policy.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Sometimes, life is complicated. Sometimes two rules conflict - the one that says you're not allowed to make up reasonable data but must rerun the tedious process, and the one that says the company won't get paid (or will get fined, or something) if the data isn't submitted on time. Bosses are sometimes in a position to make decisions like this when the people who report to them are not. In those companies, the regular people will be told that under no circumstances can they make up data and they will be fired if they do, but the truth may be that the boss is allowed to authorize making up data and will not be fired.

Alternatively, the boss is a lazy cheat who thinks the rules are only for the entry level people.

These two circumstances are hard to tell apart. But your friend probably doesn't have to. In both cases going to the boss and saying "it looks like you made up data back on the 19th of last month" will get you exactly nowhere. Either it's fine, or it's not fine but the cheating lazy boss is going to say it's fine.

If this was a matter of life and death, (like [Walkerton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Walkerton_E._coli_outbreak), where people routinely made up the "results" of water contamination measurements that had not even been taken, and 6 people died and many more were sick) I would tell your friend to find a new job then whistle blow. You say it's not. Well then, some workplaces are contradictory and confusing. Sometimes bosses are allowed to do things regular folk are not. Sometimes they aren't allowed to but they do anyway and no-one will thank you for reporting it. For now I would suggest to your friend that keeping a record of the evidence (with dates and times) is appropriate. Maybe this happens once a month, maybe once every few years. Maybe it's clearly fraudulent; maybe it's a reasonable approximation to what really happened, done in the name of expediency. Maybe after a few months your friend will know more clearly what to do about it.

Comment: TL;DR make sure it can't be attributed to you and then mind your business

Comment: One addendum, don't lie if asked about it directly from someone higher up than the boss, but don't volunteer the info either.

Comment: @kate-gregory, the data in question does have a rollover period, so while they can keep a record of the date and values it will eventually (within a month)  be deleted from the program. Does this impact your statement of keeping a record, since there will be nothing but a JR employees word citing the incident?

Comment: That's the point of keeping a record. You have like a word document and you put notes and screenshots in it. Call it something neutral like discrepancies, not "data faking". If you can tell who did it, keep that in there too. But super neutral like you're just investigating why sometimes things don't match up. The record is mostly for deciding if you want to escalate, not proving malfeasance if you do escalate. But a screenshot is obviously more compelling than a paper note with some numbers copied onto it and the originals are no longer online.

Comment: The phrase "On accident V discovered" bears a bit of examination. This looks a lot like V was snooping on data that their boss had collected. Is this in the normal scope of V's processes, to review previously collected data? Was this discovery really inadvertent, during the course of something that they really should have been doing? Expect this aspect to be examined very closely if V reports this.

Comment: @CCTO They frequently go through the logs as part of the process to record the data. They had noticed that the boss was able to complete the task much quicker with many fewer attempts and was looking to see if they (V) was doing something wrong, when they discovered the conflicting reports.

Comment: @conflicted-for-a-friend: that makes sense. So their discovery really was innocuous. Now, is it deniable? If ever someone else discovers this, and reports it, will it come back that V "must have also seen it and ought to have reported it and must be in collusion"? Or can V reasonably say "gosh, no, I really didn't notice that, even though I was doing all my own tasks just fine"?

Comment: @CCTO , Correct - after discussing thoroughly with them last night they did not seek out this discovery and has no ill-will towards the individual. They do feel a moral obligation but as posts above suggest it could be misdirected.  Unfortunately I do not have enough information to answer the second point.

Comment: @KateGregory , regarding the screenshots, if the system is external they would have to use a personal phone to take pictures, which could arise suspicion in itself and possibly be against policy. Should they proceed with this or just take hand notes on the values vs recorded?

Comment: To the first point, as an attorney I have training, experience, responsibilities, and (significantly) a license that my paralegals don't. I do things all the time that my paralegals are not allowed to do. Sometimes if I have to do things that they normally handle I can take shortcuts that they are forbidden from taking. Its not clear if this situation is analogous or not. There's no way to know that without a lot  information, but situations where supervisors can legitimately take shortcuts that the rank and file cannot are common.

Comment: @conflicted-for-a-friend I couldn't possibly advise at that level. If for some reason taking a screen shot on whatever device your friend uses to connect to the external system, and saving on that device, is against the rules, I can't suggest what might be a better plan.

Comment: There are regulated industries where a company would have formal reporting structures and QA is a requirement with an obligation to report, and there are unregulated industries where it will only impact you if the customer discovers it,.

Answer (score 38):

> What is the best way to report this kind of finding? What are the likely impacts to the career/employmeent of V in this case?

I think your friend needs to re-think their approach to this case.  Reporting this kind of finding would be the last step that they would take.  If V is really concerned about these findings then V should speak to the person who ran those tests and reported the findings (i.e. their boss).

Rather than accuse the boss of falsifying data, they can let the boss know that the data does not match with the results of the test and ask them to explain why the data is different.  Maybe when the boss ran those tests and reported the data it was acceptable to do some sort of rounding of the numbers.  Maybe there are external factors that were taken into consideration and required the test results to be adjusted.  The simplest way to get some insight is to ask the source.

Obviously, V should not be implying or accusing the boss of falsifying anything without evidence.  Extreme care should be taken in how they ask about the discrepancy.  V can say something like:

> Hey boss, I noticed that the results of tests X and Y don't match with the reported data.  Is there some other data that was factored in to achieve these results? In my tests the numbers usually match, so I am wondering if there is any data that maybe I am not taking into consideration.  I would like to better understand the process so that I can report the most accurate numbers.  Thanks.

The boss' response will give a better indication of whether or not falsification was occurring and what the next steps would be.

Comment: Always assume ignorance or stupidity over malice. And by stating it so that you're assuming its your own stupidity or ignorance being put in question, you avoid putting the other person in a defensive position.

Comment: I don't necessarily disagree with your answer but if you follow this advice and then anonymously report the problem later, you are surely going to end up on a short list of suspected reporters...

Answer (score 12):

Each level of authority and responsibility have its own horizon view of things and level of responsibility.

IMHO, it is not your friend`s business to analyze and address behavior of his boss

His job is to do the job - sorry or redundant wording

Comment: +1 Your job is not your bosses job and the rules that apply to you do not necessarily apply to your boss.  Just because you don't have the authority to make a judgment call on data doesn't mean your boss isn't authorized to do it

Answer (score 11):

The best way to report the problem is not to report the specific problem but the general underlying problem with the system that allows specific problems to happen and not get detected. This also helps reduce and prevent the likelihood of retaliation since the manager is not being called out on their actions.

### Quality Assurance (QA)

This is where quality assurance comes in.  If there is a system that is producing data that can be wrong whether it is because of accident, maliciousness, laziness, or any mired of reasons, then said system needs to have some kind of QA being done on it that can detect problems.

For this friend I am assuming there is no QA system in place taking samples, reviewing the data, or having people unknowingly redo data and comparing it to see if it matches.  The best solution would be to think of how to implement a QA system that works and get it documented and propose it to the manager or whomever is responsible for the system.  Do no cite or reference any specific incident, only mention the possible ways things can go wrong.

Odds are the manager or leader will reject the idea saying that it is too expensive or they do not have the time or resources to implement it.  In the event that happens keep records of the documentation and idea and then whenever the next incident that comes to light where someone is getting disciplined or the company being sued, bring it up again.  If the company turns down adding QA again, then you have your answer:  **They do not care**, at which point your friend should no longer care what your manager does with the data, only that they themselves are doing everything correctly.

Comment: It's an excellent idea for V to propose a "second set of eyes" process, and while V is still kind of new may be a good time to float it, blue-sky like. As Anketam says, if the company doesn't see the need, then V should feel free to make sure their own work is spotless and not to worry if the company seems to tolerate discrepancies in others', if this isn't a life-safety situation.

Answer (score 0):

Mind your own business and do what your job is to do. Don't bother what others do or don't unless it directly affects your job. Definitely, there will be consequences and your friend's work-life will be affected for sure moving forward if he/she choose to report the boss.

Answer (score 0):

As most/all other answers have said: mind your own business and do as you're told. This is obviously assuming that there is no actual damage (i.e., this is not in a medical company where the faked test results would lead to wrong dosages for important medications, and such). Not only is it possible that the boss knows more than you know; it could also be that he has direct communication with whoever requires the data to be correct, and has cleared this up directly with them. I.e., maybe it is a matter of people getting a stubborn process to work, fully aware of the side effects and real-world consequences. If this is a process internal to your company, he might just *know* from year-long experience that even though these values are wrong, everything will still be fine.

This happens plenty often in business. As long as no laws are broken, or humans or otherwise are in danger, there is no reason to have a moral dilemma. If the worst thing that can happen is a civil lawsuit because your company is the contractor, and the customer was *not* in the boat regarding the falsified data, then so be it. As long as you are in the clear - you did not do it, and there is nothing leading to falsified proof against you - it should not really concern you.

Now, if it was *not* your boss that did it, the situation would be different; if it were a completely different team, I would definitely suggest for you to inform your boss. If it was a senior team member of yours (but not your boss), then that would probably be the most difficult decision for you - "ratting" on people on your same level can backfire the most...

One thing your friend *can* do is to simply talk with his boss about the situation. I.e., chat with him about how long it takes himself, and that he noticed that the boss was much faster - maybe the boss has tips for him on how to get the results quicker; more like asking for coaching than anything else. And I mean this as a *real* chat/talk - not an indirect accusation, but actually to find out what the objective reason is. Obviously this runs a certain risk based on the character of the boss, and what actually is going on. If the boss is not necessarily the type who is easily accessible, then just forget about it.